# shall I ask forgiveness for others for others?

Tags: forgiveness

FORGIVENESS
Asking forgivness to Allah almighty for * my parents,

- relatives,
- a stranger who is a muslim

Comment: No , I'm asking for the person who is alive

Comment: It is the same for a living person.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Walaykum

It is forbidden, in the opinion of many scholars, to ask Allah to forgive a kafir.

(May Allah have mercy on him) Al-Nawawi said:

According to the text of the Qur'aan and scholarly consensus, it is haraam to offer the funeral prayer for a kaafir and ask for forgiveness for him.

It is acceptable to offer dua for the forgiveness of the sins of your family members, parents, and strangers if they are Muslims. Both live and dead beings apply.

If they are not Muslims, then you should not ask for Allah to forgive them, instead ask Allah to guide them.